# I can't find "Include" method with lambda expression in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using entity framework and I can't find include method like in this example:

```
using(ArticleExtractorEntities db=new ArticleExtractorEntities())  
{
    Preference pref= db.Preferences.Include(
```

here i find only the function include with the parameter (string path) and I don't find any other overload so how can I use Include with lambda expression?

Comment: You need to be using EF 4 **.1** or later. Note that what ships with VS 2010, is EF 4, which *doesn't* have this.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

it's not in System.Linq. 
Add

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

Comment: @ahmadhori you're in linq to entities, or linq to sql ?

Comment: Since the latest updates, this has been moved. Please see my answer below if you've upgraded your framework.

Answer (score 12):

Update. For those looking how it extend your linq query with .Include()

No longer is it:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

With netcoreapp1.0 it is:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: And that's not just for those using "EF Core?" (or ".Net Core" if you will)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it [as shown in this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entity-framework-include-with-func-next.aspx):

```
public static class ObjectQueryExtension
{
    public static ObjectQuery<T> Include<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> mainQuery, Expression<Func<T, object>> subSelector)
    {
        return mainQuery.Include(FuncToString(subSelector.Body));
    }
    private static string FuncToString(Expression selector)
    {
        switch (selector.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                return ((selector as MemberExpression).Member as Reflection.PropertyInfo).Name;
            case ExpressionType.Call:
                var method = selector as MethodCallExpression;
                return FuncToString(method.Arguments[0]) + "." + FuncToString(method.Arguments[1]);
            case ExpressionType.Quote:
                return FuncToString(((selector as UnaryExpression).Operand as LambdaExpression).Body);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    public static K Include<T, K>(this EntityCollection<T> mainQuery, Expression<Func<T, object>> subSelector)
        where T : EntityObject, IEntityWithRelationships
        where K : class
    {
        return null;
    }
    public static K Include<T, K>(this T mainQuery, Expression<Func<T, object>> subSelector)
        where T : EntityObject
        where K : class
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following articles:

http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/

http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entity-framework-include-with-func-next.aspx