# better way to do a linq query - need to reach foreign keyed data by traversing the data structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using C# 6 and EF 6 in visual studio 2017.

I have a table (SQL Server) setup with a simply foreign key constraint for looking up things like item_type to a item_type_description
.
If I just pull the main data like so, I can quickly dump everything to a data table (assuming I want all the fields):

```
   var dataPull = (from dp in aDb.TNG_RMA_items
                        select
                        dp).ToArray();

        collected_scan_dataGrid.DataSource = dataPull;
```

But as soon as I need to traverse the datastructure to get to another table such as:
dp.item_types.short_description

I then have to do something like:

```
 var dataPull = (from dp in aDb.TNG_RMA_items
                        select
                        new
                        {
                        dp.item_number,
                        dp.RMA_as_scanned,
                        dp.item_types.short_description
                        }).ToArray();

        collected_scan_dataGrid.DataSource = dataPull;
```

Now, this is fine for a small number of fields, but this table for instance has about 30 of them and I just need them all -- not a subset.

What options do I have?

Joe

Comment: If you need all 30 child relations, then you need to specify all 30 properties. There's no shortcut here.

Answer (score 0):

See [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232.aspx).

```
var dataPull =
    aDb
    .TNG_RMA_items
    .Include(dp => dp.item_types)
    .ToArray();
collected_scan_dataGrid.DataSource = dataPull;
```

Comment: It states "cannot convert lamda express to type "string" because it is not a delegate type.  Any idea what that means?

Comment: It means the `Include` call is expecting a `string` parameter instead of a `delegate` type (lambda expression) parameter. See [I can't find “Include” method with lambda expression in Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11259483/580951)

Answer (score 0):

This is very untested, and probably a very bad idea, but you could use the EF Metadata:

```
static class Ext {
    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) {
        using (var db = GetContext(query)) {
            var workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
            var itemCollection = (ObjectItemCollection)(workspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));
            var entityType = itemCollection.OfType<EntityType>().Single(e => itemCollection.GetClrType(e) == typeof(T));

            foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.NavigationProperties)
                query = query.Include(navigationProperty.Name);
        }

        return query;
    }

    private static DataContext GetContext(IQueryable q) {
        if (!q.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1")) return null;
        var field = q.GetType().GetField("context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (field == null) return null;
        return field.GetValue(q) as DataContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  While I applaud your effort and thinking outside the box this adds too much complexity to the solution - meaning the other programmers down the road would probably hate me.  But I *love* the comment of "..and probably a very bad idea"!

Comment: While researching this, I did come across someone who implemented a type-specific `IncludeAll` extension that encapsulated adding all the includes in an extension function for a specific entity.