# Issue with lambda expressions in c# data retrieval

Tags: c#, lambda

i'm writing a system to track observation values from sensors (e.g. temperature, wind direction and speed) at different sites.  I'm writing it in C# (within VS2015) using a code-first approach.  Although i've a reasonable amount of programming experience, I'm relatively new to C# and the code-first approach.

I've defined my classes as below.  I've built a REST api to accept observation reading through Post, which has driven my desire to have Sensor keyed by a string rather than an integer - Some sensors have their own unique identifier built in.  Otherwise, i'm trying to follow the Microsoft Contoso university example (instructors - courses- enrolments).

What I am trying to achieve is a page for a specific site with a list of the sensors at the site, and their readings.  Eventually this page will present the data in graphical form.  But for now, i'm just after the raw data.

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }
}
public class Sensor
{
[Key]
    public string SensorName { get; set; }
    public int SensorTypeId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Observation> Observations { get; set; }
}
public class Observation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SensorName { get; set; }
    public float ObsValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObsDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I've created a View Model for the page I'm going to use...

```
public class SiteDataViewModel
{
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Sensor> Sensors { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Observation> Observations { get; set; }
}
```

and then i try to join up the 3 classes into that View Model in the SiteController.cs...

```
public actionresult Details()
var viewModel.Site = _context.Sites
                .Include(i => i.Sensors.select(c => c.Observations));
```

i used to get an error about "cannot convert lambda expression to type string", but then I included "using System.Data.Entity;" and the error has changed to two errors... on the 'include', I get "cannot resolve method 'include(lambda expression)'...".  And on the 'select' i get "Icollection does not include a definition for select..."

There's probably all sorts of nastiness going on, but if someone could explain where the errors are (and more importantly why they are errors), then I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your ViewModel is setup, you're going to have 3 unrelated sets of data. Sites, sensors, and observations. Sites will have no inherent relation to sensors -- you'll have to manually match them on the foreign key. Realistically, your ViewModel should just be a list of Sites. You want to do
 `@Model.Sites[0].Sensors[0].Observations[0]`
not something convoluted like
`var site = @Model.Sites[0]; var sensor = @Model.Sensors.Where(s => SiteId == site.Id).Single();` etc...

Try doing
`viewModel.Site = _context.Sites.Include("Sensors.Observations").ToList();`
[Eager-loading multiple levels of EF Relations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) can be accomplished in just one line.

One of the errors you reported receiving, by the way, is because you're using 'select' instead of '**S**elect'

And lastly, be aware that eager-loading like this can produce a huge amount of in-memory data. Consider splitting up your calls for each relation, such that you display a list of Sensors, and clicking, say, a dropdown will call an API that retrieves a list of Sites, etc. This is a bit more streamlined, and it prevents you from getting held up because your page is loading so much information.

**Update**
I've [created a sample application](https://github.com/SteveV0189/SitesApp) for you that you can browse and look through. Data is populated in the `Startup.Configure` method, and retrieved [in the `About.cshtml.cs` file](https://github.com/SteveV0189/SitesApp/blob/master/SitesApp/Pages/About.cshtml.cs) and the [`About.cshtml`](https://github.com/SteveV0189/SitesApp/blob/master/SitesApp/Pages/About.cshtml) page.. This produces [this page](https://shifty.site/00Kyl), which is what you're looking for I believe.

Comment: thanks for the input - Its not obvious to me what you are suggesting around the "@model.sites[0]" etc.  That looks like a change to the view. 
 Can I ask what change you are suggesting I make to the viewModel/models ??  I've tried your suggested piece of code, but I'm now getting <cannot resolve method "include(lambda expression"> on the "include" and an error on the observations.  Point taken on the other paragraphs, but I'm trying to get <some> data back first, and then i can work on streamlining the process (like having date ranges in the observations etc).

Comment: Your DB objects are related via foreign key. You want to preserve that relation when you pass them to the frontend. By having three separate fields in your viewmodel, you are essentially breaking that, and you will have to manually re-establish that relationship via key lookups. [Follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259483/i-cant-find-include-method-with-lambda-expression-in-entity-framework) if you're having trouble using LINQ with #Include.

Comment: i think my problem lies with the "by having three separate fields".  How do i build my viewmodel to preserve the foreign keys - I assume i've done it wrong above.  And then how do I populate it in the controller?

Comment: Sites is a collection of Site. A Site object has a collection of Sensor. So you want to do Sites[0].Sensors[0].Observations. Your _current_ ViewModel has 3 separate lists. You want one.

Comment: i'm obviously missing something here - i've tried making defining my viewmodel as sites[0] - but VS rejects this, so that presumably isnt what you're telling me to do.  I understand what I need to do, i just dont understand how to implement it.

Comment: I've updated my answer and created a sample application for you.

Comment: so it seems you're using .net core, whilst I'm using vs 2015 without that installed.  this will probably explain a lot - just a "moment" whilst I install vs2017....

Comment: The architecture is different but the gist of things remains the same. I have 2 sites, 2 sensors, and 4 observations in the database, and I retrieve them all with a single call and loop over them.

Comment: installed vs2017, updated to .net core2, then getting system.object does not exist errors.  finally got it to work - huzzah, i'm just looking to get to grips with it...

Comment: ok - i can see what you've done and it works (obviously), however, my app is now broken with all the updates !  <bangs head against the wall>  Any suggestions for a book from which to learn "build a Db based website using asp mvc core in a week"  ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro start there, read every line, and it should not take you long at all. Best of luck, friend.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can you use like

```
viewModel.Site = _context.Sites
                .Include("Sensors).Include("Sensors.Observations");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you left out a " somewhere.  I took a guess at straight after the first Sensors (.include("Sensors").Include....).  That gives a different error "cannot implicitly convert type "system.data.entity.infracstructure.dbquery<project.models.site> to project.models.site.

Comment: " after Sensors `Include("Sensors").Include("Sensors.Observations")`

Comment: "after sensors"??  the rest of the code is what i had guessed at, and that gave the above errors.  So i changed "viewModel.Site" to "viewModel"  though actually its "var viewModel" instead of "var viewModel.Site" (i've changed the original question.  That is accepted by VS.  but on run time in the view, "@Model.Site.Name" gives the error System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Project.Models.Site>' does not contain a definition for 'Site'.  So i'm no closer to a working solution